# Can't use order when grouped by in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to group by FECHA_COMPRA and then order by the same field. But when I do this, I get an error message:

```
SELECT list expression references column FECHA_COMPRA which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [28:13]
```

This are the querys I'm using:

```
Select DATE(FECHA_COMPRA) as Date,TYPE,SUM(AMOUNT) AS Total, SUM(Quantity) as Qty FROM Test
GROUP BY DATE(FECHA_COMPRA)
Order by date(FECHA_COMPRA)
```

This is also not working:

```
Select DATE(FECHA_COMPRA) as Date,TYPE,SUM(AMOUNT) AS Total, SUM(Quantity) as Qty FROM Test
GROUP BY DATE(FECHA_COMPRA)
Order by FECHA_COMPRA
```

What is wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below instead

```
select 
  date(fecha_compra) as date,
  type,
  sum(amount) as total, 
  sum(quantity) as qty 
from test
group by date, type
order by date
```

Comment: consider also voting up the answer if it helped :o)